Convert NCHAR to CHAR in ADS
How can I convert a value from NCHAR to CHAR in Advantage Database Server?
For example, if I execute the following query:
SELECT CAST('Abc记开披酷' AS SQL_CHAR) FROM system.iota;

I will get the error

"poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError =
5211;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5211:  There is
an error converting Unicode string to or from code page string.  Some
Unicode characters cannot be converted to code page characters."

I'm quite happy if I get a string like "Abc????".
But how to get such a result? How to avoid the error?

Write a recursive cte that translates character by character.
